# How to valid DECIMAL with regex?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql column with this type: DECIMAL(10,2). How can I validate a price with a regex in php that is DECIMAL(10,2)?

Comment: Ask yourself: What are valid inputs and what are invalid ones. Then write a regex that only accepts the former and rejects the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The correct regex for matching numbers with commas and decimals is as follows (The first two will validate that the number is correctly formatted):

---

### decimal optional (two decimal places)

```
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YSCk5jd2XjmtM6U_)**

**Explained:**

```
number (decimal required)

^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}$

Options: case insensitive

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match a single character present in the list below «[+-]?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   The character “+” «+»
   The character “-” «-»
Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{1,3}»
   Between one and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,3}»
Match the regular expression below «(?:,?[0-9]{3})*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   Match the character “,” literally «,?»
      Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{3}»
      Exactly 3 times «{3}»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{2}»
   Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

***Will Match:***

```
1,432.01
456.56
654,246.43
432
321,543
```

***Will not Match***

```
454325234.31
324,123.432
,,,312,.32
123,.23
```

---